# How to report issues with the mobile SE application

Tags: discussion, support, ios-app, mobile-app

There's a great thing, stack exchange application (I'm using it's version for iOS). However, it has bugs so I want to know - is it correct to create threads for bug-reports on meta site? SE application isn't part of web-environment, so I doubt. Same question about feature-requests.

If it's not a good idea to create bug reports/feature requests for SE application here, then where that should be asked?

Comment: Yes; see the [tag:ios-app] tag.

Comment: Fine, thank you. If you wish, post that as an answer

Comment: If you were too look in the help section inside the app you would see it specifically says (at least on the android version) that bugs/feature requests should be posted here.

Comment: For greater good (or bad) I never used "help" section (since all interface parts were easy to understand). Now I see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The app explicitly asks you to report bugs you find. This is a part of the help page:

> Crash reports are automatically reported back to us. Bugs or feature requests should be reported on [Meta Stack Exchange](http://meta.stackexchange.com) and tagged [ios-app](/questions/tagged/ios-app).

So please report bugs using the [Ask Question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Make sure to check for duplicates though and try to make the bug report reproducible.

Comment: Yes, didn't notice that app has "help" section with this information.