# Stack Exchange App keeps crashing

Tags: bug, ios-app

After the latest update the app crashes every time I open to view a question and then once I start scrolling it crashes this happens every single time, very annoying.

I went into Settings -> Privacy -> Diagnosis but I couldn't find any file crash with having the name stack exchange

- App Version: 1.6.3.6
- Device: iPhone 6
- OS Version: Version 8.3 (Build 12F70)

Comment: Can you provide a crashlog or other more detailed information?  I can't reproduce.

Comment: @JAL how can I do this?

Comment: Is your storage full?

Comment: @Panda nope, more than 30 GB free space

Comment: @Tak Oh, then I'm not sure. Usually, mine crashes whenever my storage is almost full

Answer (score 1):

[Crash logs are automatically reported to developers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/236741/339911). So there is no need to do it manually.

To prevent crashing you could try any of Crash Recovery options from iOS system settings:

> [image: recovery]

After upgrading to 1.6.4 (TestFlight) but on iOS 10, I also had an issue with crashing. Crash Recovery options helped me.

Another problem may be due to you using old iOS version. See Brian's answer for another question [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/290175/339911).

Comment: mmm, so this means they already know that? It would have crashed more than 100 times last week. Also where on my iPhone can I find the cash recovery settings?

Comment: @Tak If auto crash reporting works as expected, developers should get them. You can find settings by tapping on the gears icon on main iOS screen, then go to app list and find Stack Exchange app.

Comment: I tried enabling them but it is still crashing :(

Comment: @Tak try to re-install the app. Also, try to log out from your account and log in again. (in the app.)

Comment: @ShadowWizard I tried both suggestions and the apps still crashes.

Comment: @Tak try to update iOS then :)

Comment: @alexolut well, I don't want to do this :)